# c++ function pointer evaluates to 1

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

I define a simple function pointer pointing to a function, and when i try to output it evaluate to 1. What is happening behind the scene? (I am on mac, compiling with c++11 g++ compiler)

```
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    return 5;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int (*fcptr)()  = foo;

    std::cout<< fcptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is 1.

Comment: You probably forgot to invoke the function via the function pointer... Add `()` to invoke the function... if that's what you want.

Comment: Do you want the pointer value or to execute the pointed-to function and capture the return value?

Comment: Hi I want to print the address of the function in memory space.

Comment: cast it to `void*`

Comment: the reason You getting 1 is somehow g++ (tested under Centos 7, g++ 4.8.5) compiles Your code to call operator<< (bool) which gives not-NULL=true=1. You need to cast fcptr to int, void*, etc. to get actual function address. btw Your code gives correct address in MSVC.

Comment: this is definitely not a dupilicate of the marked question. this is some whacky compiler specific behavior. even cout << addressof(*fcptr) prints 1. prtinf("%p", fcptr) yields the correct result.

Comment: @Josh `printf("%p", fcptr);` is undefined behaviour  , `%p` is only for `(void *)` argument

Comment: Have linked this question to one that both explains the output `1` and suggests how to output the function pointer in other ways, since OP indicated in comments that they wanted to do so

Comment: @M.M fair enough on undefined behavior. you'd be pretty hard pressed to find an example of a pointer that didn't print via %p on modern architecture i imagine. casting a function pointer to void* is undefined as well, no? anyway, for whatever reason, msvc chooses an appropriate << overload and prints the pointer.

Comment: @RetiredNinja such a cast is conditionally-supported (some compilers may not support it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no overload of `operator<<` which takes `std::ostream` and a function pointer. However, there is one that takes `std::ostream` and a `bool`, and there is implicit conversion from function pointers to bool.

So your code converts the function pointer to `bool`, which is defined as yielding `true` if it was not a null pointer; and then outputs `true` , which is defined as outputting `1` by default.  You could do `std::cout<< std::boolalpha << fcptr;` to see `true` outputted.